# Trying to get a string from Angular UI Modal via resolve object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular UI modal directive: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I'm trying to pass a string from my modal open() function to my modal controller via the resolve object. I feel like I'm doing the right thing, but somehow it isn't working.

Modal open() function:

```
$scope.showCommentModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "templates/text-entry-modal.html",
        controller: "TextEntryModalCtrl",
        resolve: {
            value: function () {
                alert("VALUE");
                return "Hello"
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Modal controller:

```
.controller("TextEntryModalCtrl", ["$scope", "$modalInstance", function ($scope, $modalInstance, value) {
    alert(value);
    $scope.value = value;
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
    };
}]);
```

The alert in the open function shows every time, right before the alert from the controller, so it's doing *something*, but when it gets to the controller, value is undefined.

One thing to note is that these controllers are *not* global variables. The example in the link above is using those, but that's not best practice for us.

Also, I have read this post: [Angular-ui modal, sending data into modal controller from $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871810/angular-ui-modal-sending-data-into-modal-controller-from-http)

I feel like this is very close to the answer I'm looking for, but I don't think I'm waiting on a promise to resolve in this case, am I? As far as I can tell, our implementations are very similar, but again I'm not using global variables but they are. Or maybe I just don't understand what's actually going on here. Of course, I don't have enough points to just ask that, so here I am...

Comment: I think you would have to inject "value" into your TextEntryModalCtrl as well.

Comment: You may need to inject the value object as well as the $scope and $modalInstance services - like ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "value", function($scope, $modalInstance, value){

Comment: Hahahaha holy crap that's all it was. I've been banging my head against this thing for hours. Ugh. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the first line of the modal controller, it appears the array that is the second parameter is missing `"value",` as the third item in the array (just before the final function in the array). It should be:

```
.controller("TextEntryModalCtrl", ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "value", function ($scope, $modalInstance, value) {
```

This particular bit of syntax is using the `controller()` method to add a constructor function to the `TextEntryModalCtrl` controller using Angular's **inline injection annotation** to explicitly specify both the dependencies of your controller along with the constructor function that will ultimately consume those (injected) dependencies.

Though your constructor function was written to consume 3 dependencies, you had only explicitly listed the first 2 dependencies so the `value` dependency was lost.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-scope-object
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation